# I can't create an instance of a class c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

Okay, so what I'm trying to do here is create an array of classes. My class TEAMLEADER is derived from an abstract class, Employee. However when I try to create an instance of TEAMLEADER in Main, I get an error message saying TEAMLEADER cannot be found.

```
namespace Lab3
{ 
    public abstract class Employee
    {
        protected string EmployeeName;
        protected int EmployeeNumber; 
        protected double WeeklySalary;

        public Employee (string EmployeeName, int EmployeeNumber, double WeeklySalary)
        {
            this.EmployeeName = EmployeeName;
            this.EmployeeNumber = EmployeeNumber;
            this.WeeklySalary = WeeklySalary;
        }

        public Employee(string EmployeeName)
        {
            assignID(EmployeeNumber);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return EmployeeName + " " + EmployeeNumber + " " + WeeklySalary;
        }

        protected virtual double CalcSalary()
        {
            return CalcSalary();
        }//"Virtual" is a keyword that says, "This can be overriden in the derived class."

        private static int assignID(int EmployeeNumber)
        {
            EmployeeNumber.ToString();
            EmployeeNumber++;
            return EmployeeNumber;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee[] workerarray = new Employee[4];
            workerarray[0] = new TeamLeader("Rachel", 18, 1000000.00, 52000000.00, true);
        }
    }
}
```

In a separate class/tab is the TEAMLEADER class.

```
public class TeamLeader:Employee
{

    protected double AnnualSalary;
    protected bool WeeklyGoal;

    public override void CalcSalary()
    {
        if (WeeklyGoal == true)
        { CalcSalary = (AnnualSalary / 52) * 1.10; }

        else (CalcSalary = AnnualSalary / 52);
    }

    public TeamLeader(string EmployeeName, int EmployeeNumber, double WeeklySalary, double AnnualSalary, bool WeeklyGoal):base(EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, WeeklySalary)
    {
        this.WeeklyGoal = WeeklyGoal;
        this.AnnualSalary = AnnualSalary;
    }
}
```

The problem is in my main method. I can't understand why I can't create an instance of TeamLeader. It's not an abstract class, so shouldn't Main be able to recognize it and create an instance?

Comment: Is it in the same namespace? You seem to be missing that part of the code.

Comment: It's in the same namespace (or it should be) but in a different tab.

Comment: Can you post the entirety of the teamleader file? If you're using Visual Studio, put your cursor right after the r in TeamLeader (in Main) and hit control-. (control-(period). Viusal studio should give you a suggestion.

Comment: Unless the namespace code is there, it isn't.

Comment: What is the namespace of your TeamLeader class

Comment: @ChadMcGrath - commented so it shows the entirety of the teamleader file I've added a namespace, but the error in Main is still there.

Comment: is TeamLeader in the same assembly as your main function ?

Comment: namespace Lab3
{ 
   public class TeamLeader : Employee
    {

        private double AnnualSalary;
        private bool WeeklyGoal;

        public override void CalcSalary()
        {
            if (WeeklyGoal == true)
            { CalcSalary = (AnnualSalary / 52) * 1.10; }

            else (CalcSalary = AnnualSalary / 52);
        }

        public TeamLeader(string EmployeeName, int EmployeeNumber, double WeeklySalary, double AnnualSalary, bool WeeklyGoal) : base(EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, WeeklySalary)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

Comment: Can you show use a print screen of your error message?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] carefully and [edit] your post if you are really interested in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

```
using Lab3;
```

to the top of your Main class file?

Comment: Yes, adding it to the top of the MAIN class didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Make sure you added `namespace Lab3` to the top of your file where TeamLeader class is located. Then add this line of code `using Lab3;` to the top of your main file.

**If that does not work for you try this.**

Maby you added TeamLeader class to a different assembly
To solve this.

Click on References in the assembly where your main is located

Click on Add Reference

Click on Projects > Solutions and add your assembly

*Please let me know if it worked or not*

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a public default constructor in your class?

```
public Employ()
{
}
```

When the command

```
Employee[] workerarray = new Employee[4];
```

is executed, it needs to create 4 new objects of type `Employ`, but those cannot be created because there is not a parameter-less constructor.

Comment: when you create an array it does not
create new instances of classes it only reserves space in memory